# How to get a compile available eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing a project and I need to make a small change to Eclipse (I need to turn off the sourcelookup function because it's slow).
But I can't find the source codes which are available to compile.I always get errors from those getting on the git.
So could you help me getting the source codes of Eclipse and compiling it? I'm new to Ant and Mvn.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your statement - I need to turn off the sourcelookup function because it's slow - means you do not want to compile everytime the source changes, I am answering this below.

If you want to turn off automatic build in Eclipse from the Project Menu uncheck Build Automatically menu item `Project -> Build Automatically`

This will stop auto building of your project every time you save something in your project. But be aware that you will not get your changes compiled automatically and will need to do a manual build.

Comment: No...what I mean is that, as you know, in debug mode, every time the thread is suspended, it will switch to the current line of code where it stops. But now I don't need it because the whole program is executed as stepping, so I want to cancel this function...

Comment: Wouldn't removing all the break points help? Also you can disable all the breakpoints

Comment: I need to let the program execute in stepping style because I need to output the context...remove all breakpoints and I will get nothing because the stack frames only exists when the thread is suspended